# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:unknown @5:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@126fda23)

Tags: java, android

I return an XML stream from the server and parse xml stream, but notify this mistack 
[to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmJWe.png)

```
private Boolean parseXml(InputStream iStream)
                throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            News news = null;
            // 用pull解析器解析
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(iStream, null);
            int event = parser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                switch (event) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    if (newes == null) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("newes 参数不能为空");

                    }
                    Log.i(TAG_SERVICE, "开始解析xml文件");
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    Log.i(TAG_SERVICE, "遇到启始标签 " + parser.getName());
                    if ("news1".equals(parser.getName())) {
                        String id = parser.getAttributeType(0);
                        news = new News();
                        news.setId(Integer.valueOf(id));
                    }
                    if ("title1".equals(parser.getName())) {
                        news.setTitle(parser.nextText());

                    }
                    if ("age1".equals(parser.getName())) {
                        news.setAge(Integer.valueOf(parser.nextText()));

                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    Log.i(TAG_SERVICE, "遇到结束标签 " + parser.getName());
                    if ("news1".equals(parser.getName())) {
                        newes.add(news);
                        news = null;

                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                event = parser.next();

            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the XML data that you're tyring to parse. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks,Thank you, the problem has been resolved